# How do I pause the previous project video in the Collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

This is my basic setup:

```
    let collection : UICollectionView = {
        let layout  = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let colle = UICollectionView.init(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        colle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        colle.isPagingEnabled = true
        colle.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        return colle
    }()

        collection.delegate = self;
        collection.dataSource = self;
        collection.register(vieosCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: collId)

//delete
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        collection.reloadData()
        let i = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row-1, section: 0)
        var cell = collection.cellForItem(at: i) as? vieosCell
        if cell == nil {
            collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
            cell = collection.cellForItem(at: i) as? vieosCell
            cell?.player.pause()
        }
        
    }
```

Apple's official statement:

`cellForItem`

The cell object at the corresponding index path or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

How can I get the previous item and pause the video?

Comment: try removing collection.reloadData

Comment: @MohmmadS Item is not visible, cellForItem returns nil, which is why I added reloadData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. override `prepareForReuse()` inside your custom cell class. [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)
2. Inside `prepareForReuse` , stop player and remove added `AVPlayerLayer`  layer with `removeFromSuperlayer` [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410767-removefromsuperlayer?language=objc)
3. 

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       (cell as? vieosCell)?.player?.play()
   }
```

4. 

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       (cell as? vieosCell)?.player?.pause()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Just use

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    player.pause()
}
```

in Your cell class

Comment: The previous item is still playing

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let i = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row-1, section: 0)
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: i) as? vieosCell else { return }
    cell.player.pause()
}
```

And getting the cell currently showing should be no issue implement here without the `collection.reloadData()`

in `didEndDisplay` cell is nil because is getting dequeued and trying to turn it off will not trigger

keep in mind you need the previous `indexPath` not the one that will show, therefore getting the current showing cell.

Comment: Here's how I understand what you mean,Get the current item in willDisplay and save it, then switch to the next item and pause the previous item video。I have tried this method

Comment: what saving no need to save just turn it off

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao can you try my snippet and comment your code.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the video is playing in the wrong order

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao can you explain more what wrong order is it related to indexPath ?

Comment: For example, sliding the project to the bottom and sliding it back, Item looks like it's been recreated, and it plays automatically

Comment: then at will display pause all players, and the last played cell, save a flag and in for cellForItem delegate check the flag that holds the indexPath and play the player this is simple

Comment: What should I do? Can you explain that again? Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220411/discussion-between-mohmmad-s-and-baiclassmate-xiao).